# redirect subdomain but keep URL intact

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I am pointing `blog.website.com` at `website.com/blog` correctly however I want the URL to remain as `blog.website.com`

Here is my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.website\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/website\.com\/blog" [L]
```

How can I do this?

UPDATE

I have managed to do it using the following code in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.website\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/$
RewriteRule (.*) http://website.com/blog/ [P]
```

However, now my blog images are not showing. If I put them into the `blog` folder created for the subdomain, they work, but I want to keep them inside the `website.com/blog` folder, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Which directory is `blog.website.com` pointing to?

Comment: It is pointing to `website.com/blog` and the redirect is working fine.I have used dummy words here to try and make the question easier for all who may have the same problem, my real situation is `jezz.stagdo.info` if you want to test it.

Comment: ok what is `DocumentRoot` for `jezz.stagdo.info`?

Comment: The `jezz` subdomain is at the same level as the `stagdo.info` domain, and the `/jezz` folder that it is pointing at is inside the `stagdo.info` domain. Is that what you are asking?

Answer (score 1):

Try this rule instead:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.website\.com$
RewriteRule !^blog/ blog%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Comment: That is returning

"Not Found. The requested URL /blog/ was not found on this server.Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."

Comment: That means `blog.website.com` is not pointing to same directory as `website.com`. You will need to contact your server admin and show `VirtualHost` entries for both sites.